# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [X] and [Y] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/url] which is not permitted

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, mapping, illegalargumentexception

I have no idea whats happening im just coding my stuff in eclipse and now the server wont start. any ideas? i tried deleting the snap thing in the directory but no luck . i have no idea what to do please help i have a project due later and im not done yet. i've tried googling believe me. :(

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [servlets.AddServlet] and [servlets.AddSubjectDetailsServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/AddSubjectDetailsServlet] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2024)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1918)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1913)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: open powershell and type this command `Get-Process`, if you see any process with the name 'Tomcat', take note of the pid. then use `taskkill /pid pid#`

Comment: may i ask what is powershell

Comment: it's the nix like shell that windows provides

Comment: oh. im looking at it now and there is no tomcat :(

Comment: ok, that rules out another instance conflicting hmmm. Post your web xml

Comment: of the project itself? or the web.xml of the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem is with your application, more precisely in your `web.xml` file.** If you search for the following string:

```
/AddSubjectDetailsServlet
```

You will find two occurences of it. This is what Tomcat complains about:

> The servlets named [servlets.AddServlet] and
>   [servlets.AddSubjectDetailsServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern
>   [] which is not permitted

Basically you are mapping two servlets to the same URL, so Tomcat would have **no chance to route requests properly. You need to change** one of them to something else.

Comment: I had the similar problem. But in my case the duplicity was not directly in my files but it came from a jar which I was depending up on. Then I did a grep --include=\* -r "servlet name "  .  in the webapps directory and found that there are two jars using the servlet name. I removed one among them and that solved the  issue.

Comment: I had to replaced MyServlet name in the web.xml.  I added "2" as MyServet2.  i also needed to change the name to MyServlet2 from all my jsp files. For some reason when i did move MyServlet to another folder, eclipse still think it still belongs there.